# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-n)\arctan (x/n)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) \in L^1(-\infty,+\infty)$.
Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-n)\arctan (x/n)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$.
I took $t=x-n$, and want to evaluate the these two terms' difference

Answer (score 3):

The integral is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\arctan(\frac{x+n}{n})dx$. Note for each fixed $x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x+n}{n} \to 1$, so the integrand converges pointwise to $\frac{\pi}{4}f(x)$. Note for each $x,n$, $|f(x)\arctan(\frac{x+n}{n})| \le \frac{\pi}{2}|f(x)| \in L^1((-\infty,\infty))$. So you can use dominated convergence theorem to get the result.